Will posting my preprint that was accepted Cambridge university press cause issues with peer review?
I recently published a literature review manuscript on Cambridge University press's open engage journal, it was accepted and is now available on its public website. It has yet to pass peer review in a reputable journal. I wanted to share my accomplishment (first publication, early career/Jr researcher) with friends and close peers via Facebook, and LinkedIn to share with mentors/peers, and family as well as attract future collaborations from people in my field. I need to revise the manuscript and design some diagrams/ images and supplementary material to help the reader who is less familiar with the topic visualize the information coherently before I feel comfortable submitting for peer review.
The pre-print is available on my ORCID profile and doesn't seem to be available via google scholar just yet.
I'm worried that it may cause issues with peer review, I'm uncertain whether or not it violates the "work must be novel, original, and not published prior to submission" policy in most reputable journals. The open engage author FAQs states that its acceptable to share your publication via social media and on public websites if it is accepted for publication, so no issue there it seems. I know I should check individually with each publisher to see if it's acceptable to share my pre-print on my personal accounts without it being detrimental to the chances for it to be published, but I'm wondering if it's largely acceptable in most journals.

This question is similar to: Does publishing a paper on arXiv prevent me from submitting it to a non-open access journal?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Yes, Open Engage isn't arXiv, but ultimately the answer is the same: it depends on the specific journal or publisher. This site may be useful: https://openpolicyfinder.jisc.ac.uk/

As you note, this depends on the publisher and on the field. Some are very strict, though the trend is against that older practice. Ask the publishers or read their web site author information.

@Anyon, while it technically probably is a duplicate, note that the linked question is very old and things have changed since the question and its most recent answer.

@Buffy The most recent (and downvoted) answer to that question seems mistaken, but I see no issue with the accepted answer. In fact, it might actually be more valid now than when it was posted since more fields are accepting of preprints these days...

@Anyon, I fear the accepted answer is too generous. It was posted by a mathematician, and in that field it is generally accepted. But it may be quite different for the OP, whose profile doesn't give good guidance. I think it is still field, and certainly publisher, dependent. Beware of facile answers. I still think this should be closed, but for different reasons (individual factors). Also, the OP there was in Physics, where it may also be generally accepted, but I have no knowledge of that.

@Buffy Physics is the only field in which posting preprints is even more standard than math.
